# connectTimeout in okhttp3 slows down responnse time

Tags: performance, okhttp

Ho All,
I have a odd issue with okhttp version 4.9.0. It seems to increase the response time ( client.newCall(request).execute() ). If I increase the connectTimeout to 5 seconds the response time increases to 6 if I increase it to 15 seconds the response time increases to 16 seconds. Below is how I am using the builder.

```
 client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .cache(null)
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem: when connecting to Wi-Fi, everything worked quickly, when using a mobile network, the speed dropped until the time specified in **OkHttpClient...connectTimeout()**.

To understand what’s going on, it’s worth displaying logs; to do this, implement the class:

`class PrintingEventListener : EventListener()` ,

and override all methods for outputting logs.

`.eventListener(PrintingEventListener())`

Pay special attention to **connectFailed** and **connectStart**.

Next, compare the results of Wi-Fi and mobile connections.
In my case, the **ipv6** DNS was configured incorrectly, which was used only on a mobile network. Using wifi, **ipv4** was used. A quick solution is to change the priority to **ipv4**. To do this, use the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64561870/16067747

Answer (score 0):

It is likely getting two or more routes and failing to connect to the first before the second one works. Most likely you have anetwork problem or similar and should fix that.

To confirm add a debugging EventListener

https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/

Since you haven't provided a useful reproduction, we can simulate using an additional route to test against.

```
  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .dns(object: Dns {
      override fun lookup(hostname: String): List<InetAddress> {
        return listOf<InetAddress>(InetAddress.getByName("198.51.100.0")) + Dns.SYSTEM.lookup("httpbin.org")
      }
    })
    .eventListenerFactory(LoggingEventListener.Factory())
    .build()

  val response = client.newCall(Request.Builder().url("https://httpbin.org/get").build()).execute()
  println(response.body!!.string())
```

Output will be like the following, not that the first connect takes 10 seconds (the connect timeouts) as it's hitting a dummy IP and then subsequent connections will try the second of the total 5 available IP addresses successfully and the request will continue.

```
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:01 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [0 ms] callStart: Request{method=GET, url=https://httpbin.org/get}
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:01 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [34 ms] proxySelectStart: https://httpbin.org/
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:01 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [35 ms] proxySelectEnd: [DIRECT]
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:01 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [36 ms] dnsStart: httpbin.org
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:01 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [150 ms] dnsEnd: [/198.51.100.0, httpbin.org/3.211.1.78, httpbin.org/35.170.225.136, httpbin.org/34.198.212.59, httpbin.org/52.6.34.179]
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:01 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [153 ms] connectStart: /198.51.100.0:443 DIRECT
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:11 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10164 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:11 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10165 ms] connectStart: httpbin.org/3.211.1.78:443 DIRECT
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:11 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10263 ms] secureConnectStart
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10663 ms] secureConnectEnd: Handshake{tlsVersion=TLS_1_2 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 peerCertificates=[CN=httpbin.org, CN=Amazon, OU=Server CA 1B, O=Amazon, C=US, CN=Amazon Root CA 1, O=Amazon, C=US] localCertificates=[]}
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10676 ms] connectEnd: h2
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10678 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{httpbin.org:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=httpbin.org/3.211.1.78:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=h2}
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10679 ms] requestHeadersStart
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10683 ms] requestHeadersEnd
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10903 ms] responseHeadersStart
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10904 ms] responseHeadersEnd: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://httpbin.org/get}
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10907 ms] responseBodyStart
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10908 ms] responseBodyEnd: byteCount=272
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10908 ms] connectionReleased
Nov 23, 2020 7:44:12 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [10908 ms] callEnd
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "okhttp/4.10.0-RC1", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5fbb684d-0b7fa68f2cce945f25b5f1bf"
  }, 
  "origin": "81.100.210.134", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Comment: Thanks any idea why it always goes to the limit specified by connectTimeout? My impression is it should just take the time it takes to make a connection then continue and not go to the end of the timeout so if it takes a second for the connection then it should move on the the next step. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I removed the pooling and have the same problem. If I increase the timeout the time to make a connection increases to the timeout value plus a second or two. I will look some more and get okhttp's maintainer's response. The have a good product and I am sure it can be resolved. Many Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am a project maintainer. Don't raise a bug. Can you provide the debug output here?

Comment: Hi Yuri, Here is the output. The example listener from above must have more overriden methods. I set the connection timeout to 5 seconds. I/System.out: 0.000 callStart
I/System.out: 0.001 dnsStart
I/System.out: 0.155 dnsEnd
I/System.out: 5.821 callEnd

Comment: Yep. Try this one https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-logging-interceptor/okhttp3.logging/-logging-event-listener/

Comment: I/System.out: 0.000 callStart
I/System.out: 0.001 dnsStart
I/System.out: 0.155 dnsEnd
I/System.out: 5.821 callEnd

I/System.out: 0.000 callStart
I/System.out: 0.001 dnsStart
I/System.out: 0.218 dnsEnd
I/System.out: 0.219 connectStart
I/System.out: 5.246 connectFailed
I/System.out: 5.248 connectStart
I/System.out: 5.296 secureConnectStart
I/System.out: 5.402 secureConnectEnd
    5.403 connectEnd
I/System.out: 5.404 connectionAcquired
I/System.out: 5.819 connectionReleased
    5.820 callEnd

Comment: Looks like your DNS is returning two routes and first one is timing out. You can adjust the logger to print DNS records. Maybe a bad host. Or ipv6 that isn't supported by network?

Comment: Sorry stack overflow limited my response so could not tell you I do use https in my url and the  response I get is correct even though failed it worked.

Comment: Looks like okhttp 4.9.0 starts out not using a secure connection so timeout reached then it uses a secure connection then that works. How do I tell okhttp 4.9.0 to use a secure connection especially since am using https in my request? Thanks!

Comment: The secret is that SSL is really just carried over an insecure socket. So your seeing first insecure SSL socket. Then SSL negotiation after connect. It's as designed.

Comment: Well I need it to work differently. I do not want users to wait 10 seconds or the connection timeout and I do want the set the timeout to one second. Is there a second timeout for the secure connection I can use? Thanks.

Comment: You can print out more details from the listener. Work out which hosts it is trying. Fix the network. Or filter your DNS. Sorry I can't help you further but the listener API gives you the detail you need.

Comment: The dns is correct but for some reason the ip for the first unsecure connection is wrong but the second call for a secured connection is correct. So I will see what happens with another product. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I found something that works really well and only takes 1 millisecond so over 5 thousand times faster. I will try to stay with okhttp where performance is not needed but your extra capability is needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Go with whatever works for you. The problem almost certainly is not with OkHttp but with your network or your application setup, all OkHttp can do is provide debugging APIs that let you investigate the problem.  Sorry I can solve this from your general description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am using comcast network so I have no control over what they are doing and many users use it also. I will run a test using Verizon.

Comment: I am using Android 10 on a Samsung 9+ device.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using a solution for Android mobile (smart device) when compiling to be compatible with java 1.8. Just add the below to your gradle.build file under defaultConfig section for the module where you use okhttp.
android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8