# How to improve the speed of okHttp request in my android application?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, okhttp

I am using okHttp to make an http request to fetch for JSONdata from an API, however, the response is very slow. Sometimes it takes 15-20 seconds, and sometimes it takes just 1-2 seconds. What can be causing this lag in requests, and how can I fix it?

Here is the code of my function where I am using okHttp to make the request. The lag is after I instantiate the request here `Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();`

Here is the code of the whole function -

```
private void doGetRequest(String[] time_duration) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        ArrayList<JSONObject> departureObject = new ArrayList<>();

        String url = "my_http_url"; 
        client = builder.build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build(); //here is the lag
        Log.v("called here", "made the request");

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                    try {

                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                        JSONArray jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("Flights");

                        departure_flights.clear();

                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i)

                            departure_flights.add(object);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    DeparturesActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {

                                for (int i = 0; i < departure_flights.size(); i++) {

                                    String departure_date = departure_flights.get(i).getString("FldaDT");
                                    String flight_number = departure_flights.get(i).getString("Flno");

                                    flightItems.add(new FlightItem(strDate, flight_number));

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a server issue? Try the request in postman and see if the duration still varies.

Comment: I doubt that the lag is with your client side code. It's more likely to be a lag in the api responses. Install a logging interceptor and you will be able to see how long the calls take to complete https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: When I try it on Postman, it always returns me in 1-2 seconds

Comment: You can add [TimingLogger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger) or [Trace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace) and see if there is some code that lasts too long.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating a new client per request.  Read up on https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/#okhttpclients-should-be-shared

Look at EventListener to log out the different events that contribute to the call latency https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/

Comment: Referring to the first link, so do I remove the client variable from my code altogether and initialise the build variable in onCreate?

Comment: Would you be able to edit the code above to help me through it because I dont quite get what to change

Comment: No, but take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64950688/connecttimeout-in-okhttp3-slows-down-responnse-time/64952803#64952803