# Very first HTTP request takes two minutes, then subsequent requests are fast

Tags: java, android, http, sockets

My Android app makes a HTTP request using the `URLConnection` API. When the first call to `connection.getResponseCode()` is made, it takes 128s, reliably. It returns the successful result from the server and all subsequent requests are fast.

If I breakpoint just before `connection.getResponseCode()` and make the same request to the server it returns in under 1s. **So I don't think it's the server.**

I tried profiling in Android Studio. Here's the stack trace that blocks for 120s:

[image: Java stack for slow initial HTTP request]

(Apologies but there seems to be no way to export this as text).

This doesn't particularly look suspicious - just that okhttp is calling the underlying java.net.Socket to connect which then delegates to native code which polls... I think this is the standard way legacy java.io works.

**Is there some other way I can work out what is happening here?**

This occurs on an Android 10 device, but *not* my Android 7 device - this seems to return immediately. It also doesn't occur in an Android 12 emulator.

Comment: The 128 seconds sounds a lot like a timeout or exponential backoff. Could your issue be an ipv4 vs ipv6 issue like this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77188400/1426891

Comment: The difference is around the time of the HTTPS requirement so just making sure that has been accounted for. Also check server logs for direction in investigation.

Comment: @MorrisonChang What do you mean by "HTTPS requirement [...] has been accounted for"?

Comment: @JeffBowman "The 128 seconds sounds a lot like a timeout or exponential backoff" - yes, I agree. It's not the socket timeout that's set (300s). Using wifi, not mobile data, but I'll check that.

Comment: @DanGravell Was thinking about: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config but realize that error isn't the same.

Comment: You can export CPU traces as files. Try that so we can have a better look. Also, have you tried using okhttp 4 directly instead of going through URLConnection to discard object generation as the source of the time loss?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to check the network traffic using Wireshark. Even if you don't see the TLS encrypted traffic you will see if the connection establishing itself or the TLS handshake cause the problems.

Comment: Nice ideas, will try tomorrow.

Comment: Look at the call stack, it doesn't seem that this is a TLS issue, it looks like it's waiting on the TCP connection (3-way handshake) to finish. The Wireshark capture should illustrate this.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Any references for installing wireshark, or what the best approach is?

Comment: I don't know how to install it on Android but you can install it on any computer on the local network with the Android device you are trying to test, e.g. on a Linux or Windows computer. As long as it can put the network adapter into promiscuous mode it will be able to collect packets.